# oracle 12c sql developer can't connect to it i want it back to local host

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

after oracle 12c installation i found that to connect to database i have to use https://192.168.93.133:5500/em also i have problem with sql developer i couldn't connect it i need to reconfigure it to local host

[image]

Comment: SQL Developer should be connecting to 192.168.93.133 port 1521, with a suitable service name. Aside from potential issues with DHCP, why do you want to use localhost instead?

Comment: it doesn't connect there is a problem with the sid name

Comment: You should using the service name 'Admasco', not the SID. There's a radio button to switch between them in the connection dialog.

Comment: still show errors ora 12514 if using services name or 12505 if using SID